# Lazy registration with Auth0 and Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, auth0

In Firebase, it is possible to log in a user as anonymous with a token, and when the user decides to register, just update the credentials. I have a hard time understanding whether the same is possible with Auth0.

We are now using Auth0 as identity provider, the flow is the following:

1. The user is using the app anonymously with limited access.
2. User registers in the app with Auth0.
3. Auth0 issues a token
4. Firebase receives the token and lets the user use the restricted parts. All the data generated by the anonymous user is lost

What I want to achieve:

1. When the user starts using the app, Auth0 immediately creates a user token
2. The token is valid to access certain parts of Firebase database
3. If/when the user decides to register, their token remains valid but receives additional credentials
4. Firebase lets the user use the restricted parts

Comment: From what I can see here it is not supported. You can create an issue in Auth0 Community Forum to see what is the current state. https://community.auth0.com/t/jwt-token-for-guest-anonymous-unauthenticated-users/15653/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Konrad from Auth0 Community Team. Yep as Baskaro said unfortunately it's not supported from our side of stack. It will be great if you can submit it as a feature request to our product team using our feedback form (you will be contacted by one of our product managers within 10 business days):

https://auth0.com/feedback